# Pack two numbers into one Int32

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am sending data to a connected device and have the issue come up where one integer retrunded from the device holds two id's. One is packed in the 10 LSB bits and the second is packed in the 22 MSB bits. From help on this site I found how to parse the two numbers ( i believe this is correct anyways):

```
//10 LSB bits
var nodeID = source & 0x3FF; //mask 10 LSBs

//22 MSB bits: mask + bitshift
var companyID = (source & 0x3FFFFF) >> 10;
```

Now i need to create an int32 from two numbers (10 bits and 22 bits respectively) and need some direction again. What would be the steps involved?

Thanks!

Comment: `(source >> 10) & 0x3FFFFF`: first shift right then mask

Comment: You actually don't need the second mask. `>> 10` is all you need to get the top 22 bits of an unsigned 32 bit value. (>> is a shift operation not a rotate operation). Also use unsigned integers if it's bits not numbers you are working with.

Comment: @Ian Mercer: alas, mask can be required: `>>` propagates sign bit: `-1 >> 3 == -1`: please, note, that `-1 == 0b111...1111` (all ones) is not changed since leftmost `1` is repeated 3 times

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes, for a _signed_ value but for an _unsigned value_ (which is a better choice for ops storage type) >> doesn't propagate sign bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems you have

```
   companyID  nodeID 
   <- 22  ->  <-10->
```

format. If it's your case you can

```
var nodeID    = source & 0x3FF;            // Rightmost 10 bits: just mask
var companyID = (source >> 10) & 0x3FFFFF; // Move to the right, then mask
```

Please, note that for `companyID` you should first shift it to the right in order to get rid of the leftmost `10` (`nodeID`) bits:

**Initial:**

```
   companyID  nodeID 
   <- 22  ->  <-10->
```

**After Shift** ( `>> 10`):

```
   sssssssss companyID   
   sign bits <- 22  ->
```

**After Masking** ( `& 0x3FFFFF`):

```
   00..00 companyID == companyID  
   <-10-> <- 22  ->
```

**Reverse:**

```
   var encoded = (CompanyID << 10) | nodeID
```

Comment: That worked perfect and fixed my initial code, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer

```
Value = LSB + (MSB << 10);
```

Comment: Be careful with *overflow* `+` can throw `OverflowException`. Put it as `Value = LSB | (MSB << 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like it should be more complicated than something like:

```cs
// convenience overload
public static int Pack( int x, int y )
{
  return (int) Pack( (uint)x, (uint)y);
}

// convenience overload 
public static void Unpack( int p, out int x, out int y )
{
  uint x1, y1;
        
  Unpack( (uint)p, out x1, out y1 );
        
  x = (int) x1;
  y = (int) y1;
  
}

// the guts of the pack operation
public static uint Pack( uint x , uint y )
{
  if ( ( x & 0xFFC00000u ) != 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("argument out of range", "x");
  if ( ( y & 0xFFFFFC00  ) != 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("argument out of range", "y");
  
  uint z = ( x << 10 ) | ( y & 0x000003FF );
  return z;
}

// the guts of the unpack operation
public static void Unpack( uint p, out uint x , out uint y )
{
  x = ( p & 0xFFFFFC00u ) >> 10 ;
  y = ( p & 0x000003FFu )       ; 
}
```

Comment: Alas, unlike **Java**, **c#** *doesn't have* `>>>`, it has `>>` only

Comment: `throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(x), "argument(s) out of range") ;`

Comment: This answer don't seems to be valid C#.

Comment: My bad. Kept my javascript hat on. See update answer.

Comment: @DaleK — because I realized that `type` wasn't a column in the table. Answer improved and undeleted!

Answer (score 0):

```
// MSB (Most significant bits); From left to right
// LSB (Least significant bits);  From right to left

// 10 LSBits
var result = source1 & 0x3FF;
// 10 MSBits
var result = (source1 >> 22) & 0x3FF;
// 22 LSBits
var result = source2 & 0x3FFFFF;
// 22 MSBits
var result = (source2 >> 10) & 0x3FFFFF;

// 10 LSBits pack with 22 MSBits
var result = ((source1 & 0x3FF) << 22) | ((source2 >> 10) & 0x3FFFFF);
// 10 MSBits pack with 22 LSBits (1'st variation)
var result = (source1 & 0xFFC00000) | (source2 & 0x3FFFFF);
// 10 MSBits pack with 22 LSBits (2'nd variation)
var result = (((source1 >> 22) & 0x3FF) << 22) | (source2 & 0x3FFFFF);
// 10 LSBits pack with 22 LBSBits
var result = ((source1 & 0x3FF) << 22) | (source2 & 0x3FFFFF);
// 10 MSBits pack with 22 MSBits (1'st variation)
var result = (source1 & 0xFFC00000) | ((source2 >> 10) & 0x3FFFFF);
// 10 MSBits pack with 22 MSBits (2'nd variation)
var result = (((source1 >> 22) & 0x3FF) << 22) | ((source2 >> 10) & 0x3FFFFF);

// 22 LSBits pack with 10 MSBits
var result = ((source2 & 0x3FFFFF) << 10) | ((source1 >> 22) & 0x3FF);
// 22 MSBits pack with 10 LSBits (1'st variation)
var result = (source2 & 0xFFFFFC00) | (source1 & 0x3FF);
// 22 MSBits pack with 10 LSBits (2'nd variation)
var result = (((source2 >> 10) & 0x3FFFFF) << 10) | (source1 & 0x3FF);
// 22 LSBits pack with 10 LSBits
var result = ((source2 & 0x3FFFFF) << 10) | (source1 & 0x3FF);
// 22 MSBits pack with 10 MSBits (1'st variation)
var result = (source2 & 0xFFFFFC00) | ((source1 >> 22) & 0x3FF);
// 22 MSBits pack with 10 MSBits (2'nd variation)
var result = (((source2 >> 10) & 0x3FFFFF) << 10) | ((source1 >> 22) & 0x3FF);

Choose which one you like...
```